# custom print function, print contents not showing on first event trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

To be quick and precise please [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b0qfsyxb/).On the first click on the button that has a label of "print", a new window will open (print contents) and then a print dialog will popup and should have contents as I have set up its content but there's no content showing, however there is title of the print dialog. Now if you click again (second click) to the button that has a label of "print", the contents of the print dialog is now showing, any ideas or clues about what's going on? help, suggestions, recommendation to make it always show?

here is my raw code

```
<button>Print</button>
<div id="print">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jason Guatamala</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>Somewhere</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#print").print();
  });
});
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.print = function(){
        var content =  $(this).html();
        var style = '<style media="print" type="text/css">body{font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;font-weight:500;font-size:13px;-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;}table{width:100%;font-size:12px!important;}table tr td{border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.05);padding:3px;}table tr:nth-of-type(4n+1),table tr:nth-of-type(4n+2),table tr:nth-of-type(4n+3),table tr:nth-of-type(4n+4){background:#eee}table tr:nth-of-type(8n),table tr:nth-of-type(8n-1),table tr:nth-of-type(8n-2),table tr:nth-of-type(8n-3){background:#ddd}</style>';
        var w = window.open('TT COLLECTION','', '');
        w.document.write('<html><head><title>TT COLLECTION</title><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">' + style + '</head><body><div style="font-size: 13px !important;" id="lf_print_main_wrapper">' + content + '</div></body></html>');
        w.print();
        w.close();
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the DOM of the new window has not finished rendering before the `w.print()` function is called. One approach would be to add the print function to a script tag at the bottom of the new window's HTML, so that it is executed after the DOM has finished rendering...

```
/* ... other code ... */ content + '</div><scr'+'ipt>window.print();</scr'+'ipt></body></html>');
  // don't need w.print here anymore
  w.close();
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b0qfsyxb/6/

Comment: cool, but is there a way I could close the open window after on close print dialog?

Answer (score 1):

Because `document.write` cannot update the DOM immediately & blockingly in the newly opened window. The next instruction `w.print();` will be invoked immediately.

So you can call the `print` method a bit later via `setTimeout`

```
    setTimeout(function(){w.print();w.close();}, 2000);
```

Comment: but the problem, there gonna be an instances when the contents render too long on the new open window due to server or network load performance and then the script trigger after the set timeout (2000) and then the contents still wont render on the print dialog.